# Slideshow Question - Slider for images uploaded to a node

Tags: entities, media, files, javascript

I am building a review web page. I want to be able to upload 3-5 pictures for the product to be reviewed and have those images displayed as a slideshow within the product node. Pictures are uploaded and stored as a CCK field.

I have been able to get the Views Nivo Slider to get to work for my homepage slider, but I'm not sure it if is possible to use it to build a slideshow for fields within the same node.

Is there a way to use Views Nivo Slider to showcase the uploaded images for the product node? If not, can you recommend another slideshow module?

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't specifically used Views Nivo Slider, I have used Views Slideshow to display uploaded CCK images in a view. The trick here is to use Arguments (or Contextual Filters, depending on which Views UI you're using) from the current nid, with a view that is set to display image fields.